# What do you call someone who fakes their feelings?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

I'm working on a thesis and I want the thesis to relate to myself so that I'll be able to write a lot of things about it. However, I'm stuck here because I want it to be about my tendency of faking my feelings so that I can make my best friend happy, even though I'm not. Can someone help me?

Comment: If you are feigning sorrow, a common idiom is “crying crocodile tears.” (Ex: “Spare me the crocodile tears about the Dodgers losing the World Series; you hate Los Angeles!”)

Comment: Please supply a sample sentence with a blank space ___ where you would like to use this word or expression. And please be more specific, are you looking for a noun, an adjective, a phrase or an idiom?

Comment: I think I have that word, it's an adjective, but I'd prefer to see your sentence before suggesting it in an answer.

Comment: That would be "husband".

Comment: See: “[How much research is needed – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5039)” and “[single-word-requests tag wiki](/tags/single-word-requests/info)”. In the question, we need to see exactly in what context you want to use the word or phrase – generally we want a sample sentence. Specify the criteria you'll use for accepting answers. Detail the research you've already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.). List words or phrases you've already considered but rejected, and explain why. Provide information about the connotation, register, and part of speech you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

*'my tendency of faking my feelings so that I can make my best friend happy'*

Someone who fakes feelings in order to impress others, particularly in a religious context, is called a hypocrite. But that is not what you mean. You are trying not to show your feelings in order not to depress your friend.

That is what is called '**a stiff upper lip'**.

In a time of personal stress or emotional turmoil, the top lip quivers just before the tears start to well up and fall. Restraining the first trembling of the top lip, is difficult to do; but, if managed, it prevents the process of emotional display.

> One who has a stiff upper lip displays fortitude in the face of adversity, or exercises great self-restraint in the expression of emotion

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_upper_lip)

> Notable examples in British history include, Captain Lawrence Oates's understated act of Antarctic sacrifice: aware that his ill health was compromising his three companions' chances of survival, he calmly left his tent and chose certain death